# CURL get file only if had been modified

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

how can I understand if a file was been modified before to open the stream with CURL
(then I can open it with file-get-contents)

thanks

Comment: If you have a copy of the file already you could use rsync.

Comment: too complicated for the purpose! thanks anyway

Answer (score 5):

Check for `CURLINFO_FILETIME`:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.mysite.com/index.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
$exec = curl_exec($ch);

$fileTime = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
if ($fileTime > -1) {
    echo date("Y-m-d H:i", $fileTime);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but I have another problem now!
I'm trying to obtain the date of alteration of files like:
http://streaming204.radionomy.com:80/LoveHitsRadio
I obtain this date 1970-01-01 00:59:59 of course wrong! How can i do it?

Comment: I don't think you can do that since that is a streaming radio. Glad it helped you.

Comment: If server doesn't want to return the FILETIME you can't do nothing about it. In you case it's returning 501 error. But it can be done with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` and reading `$exec` for `Last-Modified` on other sites.

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand if in this case I can do it or not!
I tried to set curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); but the $exec tells me : HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented

Comment: Yes, server doesn't want to return anything (is either responding incorrectly or needs to be upgraded).

Answer (score 1):

Try sending a HEAD request first to get the `last-modified` header for the target url for comparison of your cached version. Also you could try to use the `If-Modified-Since` header with the time your cached version is created with the GET request so the other side can respond you with `302 Not Modified` too.

Sending a HEAD request with curl looks something like this:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION , CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
$content = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl)
```

The `$content` now will contain  the returned HTTP header, as one long string, you can look for `last-modified:` in it like this:

```
if (preg_match('/last-modified:\s?(?<date>.+)\n/i', $content, $m)) {
    // the last-modified header is found
    if (filemtime('your-cached-version') >= strtotime($m['date'])) {
        // your cached version is newer or same age than the remote content, no re-fetch required
    }
}
```

You should handle the `expires` header too the same way (extract the value from the header string, check if if the value is in the future or not)

Comment: I'm new with curl, so I don't understand!